# Why can't MSBuild resolve assembly version changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

My problem seems to be relatively simple. I have a c# solution created in VS2010 with several projects with project references configured appropriately. I use MSBuild on our build machine which works fine, building in the correct order incrementally to be efficient. However, if I extend the interface (adding a public property etc.) and increment the AssemblyVersion of one of the projects that others depend on, it seems that MSBuild is unable to refresh the caching on down stream dependents and throws an error that it cannot find the previous version of the changed dll. Interestingly if I run the build again immediately afterwards, it tells me that the output hasn't changed and completes the build without error but I have no longer any confidence that it has done the right thing.

There is a file 'ResolveAssemblyReference.cache' that seems to hold the old reference and if I delete this from the obj/x86/Release folder before each build I never receive any errors but don't know if the output has/should have been rebuilt.

I would like to understand why MSBuild struggles with this and why on a second build it seems to report that the first build did actually work and that the targets are up to date.

Until I understand what is going on I am going to have to always force a rebuild of the entire solution to be certain I have compatible files.

Incidentally if I build in VS2010 I never seem to suffer this as I suspect it updates that cache appropriately each build.

Update:

I have found that my use of 'OutDir' on the command line for MSBuild seems to be to blame. If I remove this then the referencing seems to be resolved appropriately. However now I do not have my output copied to where I need it for deployment...

Comment: What do you mean by extending the interface? You mean you've added a property to your msbuild script or project file?  Can you post an example of how you're incrementing the AssemblyVersion?

Comment: I mean for example adding a public property to one of the classes defined in the project and amending the AssemblyVersion property in the AssemblyInfo.cs of that project. Like this

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.3.0.0")]

becomes

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("4.4.0.0")]